# Read an Unknown Number of netCDF Files from Ordered Directories in Python

Tags: python-2.7, netcdf4

I am trying to read a large number of netCDF files containing temperature data over three years. The files are stored in subdirectories ordered by date:

Example_directory: /YYYY/YYYY_MM_DD/file.nc

Each subdirectory /YYYY/YYYY_MM_DD/, contains an unknown number of netCDF files (ranging from 3 - 18), but the temperature data in each netCDF file has the exact same dimensions:

```
temp.shape
(1,6,60,360)
```

Eventually, I would like the temperature data to be stored in one of the following to matrices:

```
# Either...
TEMP_1.shape
(N,6,60,360)
# or...
TEMP_2.shape
(year,month,day,n,6,60,360)
```

where N is the total number of files in all the directories and n is the number of files for each date (in other words, n would vary from date to date). Either of these two matrices would be fine.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
# READ TEMPERATURE DATA
import netCDF4

print('Reading netCDF Files')
Y = [0, 1, 2]
for y in Y:
    year = str(y + 2014)
    for m in np.arange(1, 13, 1):
        month = '{:02d}'.format(m)
        for d in np.arange(1, 32, 1):
            day = '{:02d}'.format(d)
            nc = glob.glob('/'+year+'/'+year+'_'+month+'_'+day+'/*.nc')
            if nc != []: # If the file exists, then...
                nc_1 = netCDF4.MFDataset (nc[0]) # Open the ncdf file 
                TEMP = nc_1.variables['temp'][:][:]
                nc_1.close() # Close netCDF file
            print('Closed MFDataset file ' +year+'-'+month+'-'+day)
```

But this loop doesn't quite work. My understanding is that it overwrites each file with the next. For me it is a problem that the individual filenames are not ordered by date (but appear randomly given). That is why I tried to store them with MFDataset and not loop through them as I loop through the directories.

I recognize that I am semi-new to python, so my method of approach does not have to be maintained if it is very flawed. The only thing I want to achieve is to eventually store the temperature data in either the shape of TEMP_1 or TEMP_2. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have to use Python? Concatenating netcdf files can be much simpler using NCO ncecat: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ncecat (Note the main docs are down right now, but this gives you a sense of what it can do)

Comment: @N1B4 Yes, I am afraid that I need to use python. I had a look at your ncecat suggestion, though, and essentially it does what I want to do, i.e. merges all the files for one day into one file. On the other hand, this is what I attempted to do with MFDataset in my python code.